# Styling TripAdvisor widget

Tags: javascript, css

I've been asked to attach a travel advisor widget to an existing project. The problem is I can't find a way of styling it. Searching Google has proved negative and I've tried various ways to change the style myself but each time I'm getting nowhere.

It would seem (by using Developer tools) that the script is adding other div tags within the below code when it's called and it's these newly added div which I need to style.

Any ideas?

```
<div id="TA_linkingWidgetWAR281" class="TA_linkingWidgetWAR">
  <ul id="7vEu3EbbE54" class="TA_links I3eKq4As">
    <li id="P1W6bWTQjEmY" class="M0QRzat">
      Write a review of <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g1217951-d2315832-Reviews-Peking_Chinese_Takeaway-Bradley_Stoke_Gloucestershire_England.html">Peking Chinese Takeaway</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=linkingWidgetWAR&amp;uniq=281&amp;locationId=2315832&amp;lang=en_UK&amp;border=true">   </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was easy right?

All you have to do is use your browser inspector and check the current apply styles and edit at your own will...

[image]

as an example: http://jsbin.com/ivebet/2/edit

all I had to do was:

```
#CDSWIDLNKR .widLNKRInner {
    margin: 30px  !important;
    padding: 14px 16px 12px !important;
    background-color: #bada55 !important;
}
ul li img {
    display: none;
}
```

But, be careful, **you are breaking the [widget agreement](http://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/widget_terms.html)**.

> 2.1 **You may not directly or indirectly change**, edit, add to, copy or extract content from or produce summaries of the TripAdvisor Widgets or any content on the TripAdvisor website. In particular, you will not display any TripAdvisor ratings or reviews on your website outside of the TripAdvisor Widgets.

Comment: I tried that attempt but using only #CDSWIDLNKR { ... }. I didn't use both the id and class #CDSWIDLNKR .widLNKRInner { ... }. Thank you.

Comment: I advise you to read the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as well understand that you should ["pay it forward"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17886/28004) by upvote, mark as correct answer or simply answer one questions :)

Comment: WORKED A CHARM! Thank you. Upvoted.

Comment: remember that you are infringing their agreement, be careful as they can simply block your account or lawyer up...

Comment: Haha, that colour spells badass! `#bada55`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a widget the div's that you speak of are provided via the widget you are using. Other than creating a wrapper and styling it you'll likely have little control over the inner styling.

However this is what you can do. Hit F-12 (chrome for example) in your browser and inspect the additional div's that it creates. Note the classes and id's accordingly for these divs/elements.

To style them in CSS you'll also likely need at least in some cases use !important with your styles to override the default coming from the provider of the plugin. Such as this:

```
div.someclass { border: none !important; }
```

Unfortunately this is the price of using widgets, ease of use is a trade off with control.